# Getting first paragraph of most recent post based on category ID

Tags: php, wordpress

It's been a while since I've worked with PHP and WordPress, so I am a bit rusty. What I want to do is to display the opening paragraph for the most recent post under a category for a WordPress site. Based on some research I did, I've compiled this piece of code:

```
<?php
$category_id = get_cat_ID('Downtown News');
$post = get_posts( $category_id );
if( !empty( $post ) ) {
    setup_postdata( $post );
    ?><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    <?php the_excerpt();
} ?>

<?php
$post = $wp_query->post;
setup_postdata( $post );
?>
```

I have code to get the category ID I want, and I have the code to display the first paragraph of the most recent article. However, the code does not seem to work. What is displayed is the first paragraph under an "uncategorized" category of postings, which is not what I want. How can I fix what I have so that it gets the correct category?

Comment: Start with dumping with var_dump the $category_id variable to see if everything is ok. Then do that with every variable in this code. That would probably lead you somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have started at the right place: [`get_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts), however you don't have the correct parameters. So try the following out:

```php
<?php 
$args = array(
    'category'         => 'CAT_ID_1,CAT_ID_2',
    'orderby'          => 'post_date',
    'order'            => 'DESC'); 

$posts_array = get_posts( $args );
?>
```

From the function reference we know that:

> The category parameter needs to be the ID of the category, and not the
>   category name

which means that you can have one or more category IDs (comma separated).

A list of all parameters can be found [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query).

Comment: I've tried both methods suggested, but now I just get a hyperlink to the home page....

Comment: The `query_posts` methods returns an array. I cannot imagine why you gey a link.

Comment: Okay, I made some adjustments and your code is basically what I needed--I was able to find a solution because of it, so thank you!

Comment: @gallifrey1212 could you please let me know why it didn't work at first and what I got wrong?

Comment: It wasn't something you did wrong--It was something I was doing wrong with my code. I made a change in my code to have this line:    foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); That seemed to correct the issues I was having. Your code is completely fine, so don't worry.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue with yours, maybe this one will work for you

notice the `$category_id` gets pulled from `get_cat_ID()` function, this tells me you do not know the `cat_id`, you can go to the category where you created the downtown news, move your mouse over it to reveal the url address which it will tell you the category id, find that number and replace the line:

```
query_posts('cat='.$category_id.'&posts_per_page=1');
```

(using 99 as an example)

```
query_posts('cat=99&posts_per_page=1');

<?php
global $post;
$category_id = get_cat_ID('Downtown News');
query_posts('cat='.$category_id.'&posts_per_page=1');
if ( have_posts() ) { 
      ?>
      <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
      <?php the_excerpt();
}
wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Comment: Just some advice here. Never ever use `query_posts` unless you really want to break stuff on a page. It breaks the main query and all of its globals and functions that needs these globals.